# Given a list of integers, remove all values greater than 100

Tags: java, list

Basically, I am looking to write some code for a class which removes all the larger numbers bigger than 100. It needs to be written in Java. How do we do this?

We found some other code in our year drive of past work, but it doesn't quite work as it has an  "enum expected" problem. It also looks like it works for 1000, not 100?

```
        List<Integer> list =new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < given_list.length; i++) {
            if (given_list[i] < 1000) {
                list.add(given_list[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);

"enum expected" is what the Intellij tool is telling us.
```

Comment: what has this question got to do with python or javascript?

Comment: Java is similar to javascript and lots of people know python and I want eyeballs on it. How it works on Instagram.

Comment: All you will get is downvotes by doing that.  BTW, nothing looks wrong with this posted code.  I would expect it is from earlier code.  Is `given_list` defined?

Comment: Well, when I put the code into intellij it does not work.

Comment: The amount of code that you have shown is not enough to see what the error is.  [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: also, you'll need to change `given_list[i] < 1000` to be `given_list[i] <= 100`

Comment: But that's literally all the code we have. That's everything in the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the comment discussion as well as the fact that you copied the code and didn't write it yourself, I am guessing that you are trying to run that raw block of code by itself and didn't realize that it must go in some other code.

1. You must import the ArrayList and List.
2. Everything in Java must be in a class, with the name of the file matching the name of the class.
3. For your code to run from the console (which is presumably where you want to run it), it should be inside main.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] given_list = {0,4,5,56,3, 2000, 453, 5435};

         // insert your code here
    }
}
```

I've seen a lot of people try to copy their way through a programming course. The problem is, even small things like this will cripple you if you don't know the basics. At least open the first few pages.

Comment: Seriously though, this seems like a first-year first-week assignment. You need to learn things a bit more carefully.